# Nuget version and release management like maven release plugin

Tags: maven, tfs, nuget, versioning, release

I am more experienced with Java than dotnet. But, recently I have started working on a dotnet Project and I have to write CI process for this Project.

I use maven for Java. And Where is a maven release plugin. Basically, You use snapshot version during development time. and when you ready for a release candidate or release. You use maven release plugin and it update all pom files and commit the new version for you.

Is there a similar tool for nugget to automatically update version number and put tags like RC, RELEASE etc. What approach should I use.

Not: We are usign TFS 2015 for CI process. I can take advantages of TFS capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called **[Release Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/what-is-release-management)** in TFS, an essential element of DevOps that helps your team **continuously deliver** software to your customers at a faster pace and with lower risk.

> Since you are also using a continuous integration (CI) system and  you
>   could use TFS release management as a fully-fledged continuous
>   delivery system. You could set up Release Management to automatically
>   deploy new builds to multiple environments.

As for version nuget package you could take a look at below blog which shows you how to hold CI packages(part1) and share packages using Release Management(part tool) with the help of **NuGet Publisher** task.

- [Versioning NuGet packages in a continuous delivery world: part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/05/03/versioning-nuget-packages-cd-1/)
- [Versioning NuGet packages in a continuous delivery world: part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/05/18/versioning-nuget-packages-cd-2/05/18/versioning-nuget-packages-cd-2/)

Not sure maven how to handle the tags and equivalent in TFS, there is a tag in tfs build, you could add the tag manually or [through API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#addatagtoabuild), which builds actually be tagged for easy searching.

As for snapshot, there is a corresponding thing in TFS called [labels](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-labels-take-snapshot-your-files), you could directly build labels.

Comment: I have not mentioned but We are using XLRelease for release management. (Also, XLDeployment for deployments) So, We use TFS only for CI.

Comment: I think SNAPSHOT is misunderstood.  Semantic versioning: {major}.{minor}[-{stage}[.{resource-version}]] example: 1.0-preview.2 -  SNAPSHOT is very similar to preview and commonly used in Java Project. I am trying to understand how to put {stage} like "preview" while versioning artifacts.